# How to make hibernate to save entity data to all related tables at once?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have many to many relationship between `Team` and `TeamMember` using extra table `team_member`. Hibernate saves data only to `member` table ignoring `team_member`. How to make it work?

**DAOImpl**

```
public void addTeamMember(TeamMember teamMember) {
        getCurrentSession().save(teamMember);
    }
```

**Child Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="member")
public class TeamMember {
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "teamMembers", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Set<Team> getTeams() {
        return teams;
    }

    public void setTeams(Set<Team> teams) {
        this.teams = teams;
    }
}
```

**Parent entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="teams")
public class Team {

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "team_member", joinColumns =
    @JoinColumn(name = "FK_Team_id", referencedColumnName= "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "FK_Member_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    )
    public Set<TeamMember> getTeamMembers() {
        return teamMembers;
    }

    public void setTeamMembers(Set<TeamMember> teamMembers) {
        this.teamMembers = teamMembers;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you wrote mappedby on TeamMember you said to JPA that the Team will be responsible for managing this relation. It means that you have to add the Member manualy to the Team list to have it pesitsted (the cascadeType all makes sure of it).

```
TeamMember member = new TeamMember()...

EM.getTransactio().beging(); //if manage transactions manually
Team team = EM.find(Team.class,id);
team.getTeamMembers().add(member);
EM.getTransaction().commit();
```